# C++ Single linked list problem deleting node

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have written this code for deleting all nodes which are divisible
by 9.
But when I try to input two consecutive numbers that are
divisible by 9 only of them is deleted.

```
void deletebydivisable(){
    Node *currentNode = head;

    while (currentNode!=NULL){

        if(currentNode->nextNodeAddress->data % 9 == 0){
            Node *todelted = currentNode->nextNodeAddress;
            currentNode->nextNodeAddress = todelted->nextNodeAddress;
            delete(todelted);
        }
        currentNode = currentNode->nextNodeAddress;
    }
}
```

Comment: What will happen if `currentNode->nextNodeAddress` is `NULL`, I think it needs to be checked... `currentNode->nextNodeAddress->data` will fail

Comment: I check through this also but the same problem exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is wrong, for several reasons:

- you not taking into account that the `currentNode->nextNodeAddress` field will be `NULL` when `currentNode` is pointing at the last node in the list.  You should be deleting the `currentNode`, not its `nextNodeAddress`.
- you are not taking into account the possibility that the 1st node in the list may be divisible by 9, in which case you would have to update the `head` pointer to point at the 2nd node in the list.
- when deleting a node, you are not updating the `nextNodeAddress` field of the *previous* node to no longer point at the deleted node but to now point at the *next* node in the list.

Try this instead:

```cpp
void deletebydivisable(){
    Node *currentNode = head;
    Node *previousNode = NULL;

    while (currentNode != NULL) {
        Node *nextNode = currentNode->nextNodeAddress;
        if ((currentNode->data % 9) == 0) {
            if (head == currentNode) {
                head = nextNode;
            }
            else {
                previousNode->nextNodeAddress = nextNode;
            }
            delete currentNode;
        }
        else {
            previousNode = currentNode;
        }
        currentNode = nextNode;
    }
}
```

Which can be simplified slightly by using a pointer-to-pointer to eliminate the innermost `if-else` block, eg:

```cpp
void deletebydivisable(){
    Node *currentNode = head;
    Node **previousNode = &head;

    while (currentNode != NULL) {
        if ((currentNode->data % 9) == 0) {
            *previousNode = currentNode->nextNodeAddress;
            delete currentNode;
        }
        else {
            previousNode = &(currentNode->nextNodeAddress);
        }
        currentNode = *previousNode;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming if you have linked list as 9 -> 18 -> NULL

In the first Iteration `currentNode` points to `9`

As per your logic it will delete `currentNode->nextNodeAddress` which is `18` and update linked list:
9 -> NULL

and due to `currentNode = currentNode->nextNodeAddress;` in your code, 
`currentNode` will also get updated to `NULL`

So the loop ends as the while condition is false and `9` never gets deleted! You need to improve your code and dry run like this to understand better!

Comment: Okay I will dry this